# Ag-Grid onCellClicked and MouseEvent

Tags: onclick, mouseevent, ag-grid

I've been searching for hours and can't seem to find an answer. Does Ag-Grid block the click on the wheel and right mouse button?

```
onCellClicked={(cellData: CellClickedEvent) => {         
 const mouseEvent = cellData.event as MouseEvent; // Cast to MouseEvent
                  if (mouseEvent.button === 0) {
                    // Left mouse button (0)
                    console.log('Left mouse button clicked in cell');
                  } else if (mouseEvent.button === 2) {
                    // Right mouse button (2)
                    console.log('Right mouse button clicked in cell');
                  } else {
                    // Other mouse button or unknown button
                    console.log('Unknown mouse button clicked in cell');
                  }
              }}
```

I've tested this, and Ag-Grid only recognizes the left mouse button click.

Answer (score 0):

For the right mouse button you can use the **cellContextMenu** event

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/grid-events/#reference-selection-cellContextMenu

For the middle click, you can try to set **suppressMiddleClickScrolls** to **true** so that the cellClicked event is fired:

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/grid-options/?#reference-scrolling-suppressMiddleClickScrolls

Notes from the documentation:

> Not all browsers fire click events with the middle button. Most will
> fire only mousedown and mouseup events, which can be used to focus a
> cell, but will not work to call the onCellClicked function.